# JQuery get the title of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button:

```
<button type="button" onclick="toggleColor('white');" >White</button>
```

Which makes this:

[image]

Is there any way to get what is written on the button using jQuery. For example this button would return `White` because its in-between the 2 button tags.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You can get it by using `.text()`,

```
$('button').text();
```

Please read [here](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to know more about it.

Comment: I tried that and get: `TypeError: Object #<HTMLButtonElement> has no method 'text'`

Comment: It wasn't working in Chrome's console but works in a JS file. Thanks.

Comment: This works, but for some reason removes the actual button style.

Answer (score 14):

add id to your button like this

```
<button type="button" onclick="toggleColor('white');" id="your_button_id" >White</button>
```

now you can use **JS** like this

```
var button_text = document.getElementById('your_button_id').innerHTML;
```

and also you can use **JQUERY** like this

```
var button_text = $('#your_button_id').text();
```

Answer (score 9):

Try

```
$("button").click(function(){
var title=$(this).attr("value");
alert(title);
});
```

Comment: This is better because you can also use it to set the button label.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with Vanilla JS, after you've added an ID so you can fetch the element.

Assuming:

```
<button type="button" onclick="toggleColor('white');" id='myButton'>White</button>
```

You can do in JavaScript:

```
var someVar = document.getElementById('myButton').innerHTML; // -> White
var anotherVar = document.getElementById('myButton').textContent; // -> White
```

Both will hold "White"

Answer (score 2):

give the button an ID

```
<button id="btnTest" type="button" onclick="toggleColor('white');" >White</button>
```

JQuery:

```
alert($("#btnTest").text());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this `event.target`

```
$("button").click(function(event){
var text=$(event.target).attr("value")
alert(text);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just provide one id to button and use it with JQuery

```
<button id=btn type="button" onclick="toggleColor('white');" >White</button>
```

then use jquery like this

```
$("#btn").val();
```

it will work for your condition.

Comment: This might work but you shouldn't be using `val()` - The .val() method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as input, textarea, select [doc](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on chrome.

```
$("#your-button-id").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to use the `Name=` identifier (rather than `id`), you can get the button text by using:

```
$('button[Name="buttonNameHere"]').text();
```

and you can set the text by using:

```
$('button[Name="buttonNameHere"]').text("Replacement Text Here");
```

Answer (score 0):

In Jquery you can use the following code:

```
$("#button").val();
```

The above line will give the text written on the button. And for setting text on the button through Jquery use the following code:

```
$("#button").val("SAVE");
```